# Rendering a trapezoid in OpenGL without perspective

Tags: opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I am attempting to render a trapezoid using OpenGL as shown in figure 5 below

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2WYm.png) will be referenced to illustrate different types of rendering that I have tried

figure 1 is just how the quad is being triangulated as this line is present in all subsequent images

```
GL11.glLoadIdentity();      
GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glVertex4f(-1.0f, 0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glVertex4f(1.0f,  0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glVertex4f(0.5f,  1f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glVertex4f(-0.5f, 1f, 0, 1f);

GL11.glEnd();
```

figure 2 is the traditional perspective correction and causes the trapezoid to look like a square tipped back because perspective interpolation along the y axis. However the interpolation along the x axis is wanted. http://www.xyzw.us/~cass/qcoord/ describes the method

```
GL11.glLoadIdentity();      
GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(0, 16f, 0, 16f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(-1.0f, 0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(16f, 16f, 0, 16f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(1.0f,  0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(8f, 0, 0, 8f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(0.5f,  1f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(0, 0, 0, 8f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(-0.5f, 1f, 0, 1f);

GL11.glEnd();
```

figure 3 The standard rendering for trapezoids without q value modification. The lack of perspective based interpolation along the y axis is desirable; but the lack of interpolation along the x axis is not.

```
GL11.glLoadIdentity();      
GL11.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(0, 1f, 0, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(-1.0f, 0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(1f, 1f, 0, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(1.0f,  0f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(1f, 0, 0, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(0.5f,  1f, 0, 1f);

    GL11.glTexCoord4f(0, 0, 0, 1f);
    GL11.glVertex4f(-0.5f, 1f, 0, 1f);

GL11.glEnd();
```

Above Simplified. figure 2 has x axis interpolation correct but distorts y axis and figure 3 has y axis correct but no interpolation along the x axis

figure 4 shows a simplified version of how I want to render the trapezoid (via photoshop).

figure 5 is a sample texture applied (via photoshop) to the render model described in case 4.

The code listed above was done inside of java with the LWJGL (and was rendered accordingly), I am fine with answers in C or C++ as well as the code resembles LWJGL calls strongly (as LWJGL was designed to)